# How to remove a CHECK constraint from a column in Interbase 2020

Tags: sql, ddl, interbase

In Interbase (2020) I have a table CATEGORY with a field Category on which a CHECK CONSTRAINT was implemented with:

```
ALTER TABLE CATEGORY ADD 
   CHECK (Category > 999 AND Category < 10000);
```

Now I want to remove this CHECK (or ALTER it, but remove / add will do).  I have been looking everywhere but what's the syntax to remove this CHECK constraint?

Under the table DEPENDENCIES, there are CHECK_25 and CHECK_26 on CATEGORY but using something like

`ALTER TABLE CATEGORY DROP CONSTRAINT CHECK_25`

does not work. I get 'Error at line 1 - unsuccessful metadata update. Constraint CHECK_25 does not exist'

Looking at the table dependencies, CHECK_25 appears to exist.  Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the documentation.

[image]

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: Please see edited question.